# Trying to install GNOME on Ubuntu on remote server

Tags: 18.04, gnome, desktop-environments, vnc, gdm

Im a fairy new user at Linux.

I have Ubuntu 18.04 on a host at paperspace.

I'm following this guide:
https://www.teknotut.com/en/install-vnc-server-with-gnome-display-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Beside that I installed ZeroTier for VPN access.

Everything in the guide worked fine except this line:

> sudo systemctl enable gdm

I get the following error:

> The unit files have no installation config (WantedBy, RequiredBy,
> Also, Alias
>
> settings in the [Install] section, and DefaultInstance for template
> units).
>
> This means they are not meant to be enabled using systemctl.
>
> Possible reasons for having this kind of units are:
>
> A unit may be statically enabled by being symlinked from another
> unit's
>
> .wants/ or .requires/ directory.
>
> 2. A unit's purpose may be to act as a helper for some other unit
>    which has
>
> a requirement dependency on it.
>
> 3. A unit may be started when needed via activation (socket, path,
>    timer,
>
> D-Bus, udev, scripted systemctl call, ...).
>
> 4. In case of template units, the unit is meant to be enabled with
>    some
>
> instance name specified.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

No need to enable, it is get auto configured while setup. And you can change which default Display Manager you want using:

```
dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

Just reboot once.